Makefile in windows with conditional expression
I am writing a makefile for a Fortran program and I would like to use compiler switches that depend on whether I use ifort or gfortran to compile.
This is the makefile, but it gives me a syntax error:
# Select Compiler
COMPILER = ifort
#COMPILER = ifort
#COMPILER = gfortran

# Define the compiler switches
ifeq ($(COMPILER), gfortran)
    SWITCH = -O3 -Qopenmp
else
    SWITCH = /O3 /fast /Qipo /Qmkl=parallel /Qopenmp /Qparallel -qopt-matmul 
endif

#SWITCH = /Qmkl /Qopenmp /warn:all /check:all /traceback /heap-arrays0 
#GARBAGE = /fast /Qparallel /Qipo /Qprec-div- /QxHost  /heap-arrays0

SRCS =src\mod_utilities.f90 src\main.f90
    
EXEC = exe\run_win.exe

ifort:
    $(COMPILER) -fpp $(SWITCH) $(SRCS) -o $(EXEC) 
    
# Cleaning everything

clean:
    del *.mod
    del *.obj
    del *.pdb
    del *.ilk
    del $(EXEC)

#To compile in Mac, type:
# $ make -f makefile_mac

#To compile in Windows, type:
# $ nmake /f makefile_win

The error is the following:
makefile_win(8) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing


The nmake processor does not have ifeq statements. See Makefile processing

Thanks! I saw that nmake uses !IF but how would you rewrite the if else block in the makefile? Thanks!

Added answer below.

To achieve the same results in an nmake file you would need something like:
!IF "$(COMPILER)" == "gfortran"
SWITCH = -O3 -Qopenmp
!ELSE
SWITCH = /O3 /fast /Qipo /Qmkl=parallel /Qopenmp /Qparallel -qopt-matmul
!ENDIF

Note that in this case the word SWITCH must appear in column 1 of the line. Otherwise nmake thinks it is a command and tries to execute it.
